# Loop can create multiple instances of a class, but not possible on line by line?

Tags: objective-c, class, loops

So I have a simple class called CAR, with a property int called carId.

If I try to create multiple instances of the class like that:

```
Car *car = [[Car alloc] init];
car.carId = 1;

Car *car = [[Car alloc] init];
car.carId = 2;
```

It does not work, which I understand.

But if I do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++) {
  Car *car = [[Car alloc] init];
  car.carId = i;
}
```

it works. That, I do not understand why.

Would someone be able to explain the reason ? 
Thanks !

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because its quality is very low. OP should start with reading something like "Learning Objective C for 24 hours" not from posting question on SO.

Comment: Did you read the error you get with the 1st set of code you posted? Did you do any searching about the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `{ ... }` block of code creates a "context" called scope where variables can be declared. You can't have the same variable twice in the same context, or a parent context (variables are inherited by the children). For obvious reasons, or else the compiler can't figure out which one you're talking about).

In:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++) {
  Car *car = [[Car alloc] init];
  car.carId = i;
}
```

There's only one variable called `car` in the context.

In:

```
Car *car = [[Car alloc] init];
car.carId = 1;

Car *car = [[Car alloc] init];
car.carId = 2;
```

You've got two. If you change it to:

```
Car *car1 = [[Car alloc] init];
car1.carId = 1;

Car *car2 = [[Car alloc] init];
car2.carId = 2;
```

It works.

Alternatively, you can reuse that variable (but then you lose references to the first one unless you saved it somewhere):

```
Car *car = [[Car alloc] init]; // First car
car.carId = 1;

car = [[Car alloc] init]; // Second car, but now you just lost the first car reference unless you added it to a collection or something.
car.carId = 2;
```

You could also do this, and create two contexts, but then your variables aren't available outside those contexts (i.e. in the parent context).

```
{
    Car *car = [[Car alloc] init];
    car.carId = 1;
}
{
    Car *car = [[Car alloc] init];
    car.carId = 2;
}
```

Comment: this "context" is called "scope"

Comment: Hi,

Would have it work the same if I did

Car *car = [[Car alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  car.carId = i;
..?

Comment: In that case, you would be modifying the id of the same car 10 times. In the end, you'd have only one car, with a carId = 9.